# error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0', can't shut down

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

My ultra-book has dual boot of windows 10 and  Ubuntu 14.04. It was windows 7 a year ago I just upgrade it to windows 10 a month ago.

It works fine until yesterday. Today I turned it on and went to Ubuntu. The first time it shows it cant open Firefox because it's running ... something like that. So I restart my ultra book. then the error:

> error:attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.

Press any key to continue.

Then whatever key I pressed it is still the same. The power button does not work either. I can't even force to shut it down. what should I do?

Comment: Hold the power button in to force it to shut down

Comment: Did you solved the problem? Can you please share resolution I am struck in their .Please

Answer (score 0):

Try make a live version of Ubuntu and mounting the partition Ubuntu is on your hard drive. Look go to the file '/boot/grub/grub.cfg' and see if hd0 or a different drive number lives in the code.

You can see what hard drive number your grub.cfg should be on by using gparted.

Take care.